# Cant get my jawsDb add on to open from MYSQL workbench

Tags: mysql, heroku

I was able to create the connection to my jawsDB one time I didn't finish creating the table and logged out to do it the next day. Since then I can't get back in. I've tried deleting it and making a new connection as well as uninstalling it and re instaling haws to my heroku app. Does anyone have any tips on why it may have worked once but not a second time?